# Heartbeat with two machines each different network

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04, heartbeat

I am able to configure the heartbeat for two machines at same network. Properly set&configure ha.conf and haresources.

I would like to know how I can establish same configuration for two machines located at different network. I mean 
Machine 1 IP:94.55.10.10
Machine 2 IP:93.44.11.11
Machine VIP: 92.11.22.22

One solution is to establish VPN connection with two networks. But I wonder if it is possible to configure heartbeat system without any component.

Using Ubuntu 12.04 as a platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heartbeat is broadcast UDP traffic, and while broadcast traffic is routable, it isn't usually over routers you do not control, unless you use a VPN, or some other sort if tunnel.

Comment: There should be a solution in case of failure sceneario in order to move the service other location such as different city. I keep searching a way of doing this. Your answer is acceptable by the day of me finding a acceptable solution. Thanks.